# Which files are safe for deletion on Ubuntu 18.04 iso?

Tags: dual-boot

So I have a 1.85GB thumbdrive but the Ubuntu 18.04 version is 1.93GB big. I found online that I can use **isomaster** to delete some files and make the ubuntu image smaller.

However, I'm really a beginner at all of these so I'm not sure which files in the image are safe for deletion, and I can't seem to find any information online about it.

Alternatively, I'm considering the minimal Ubuntu version, since I read online that 'unminimising' it is an option. I'm not sure whether un-minimising will allow Ubuntu to run in UEFI mode afterwards though.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Thoughts... create a 2Gb partition with gparted. Put the ISO in there. Add the ISO to the grub boot and boot from the partition. Seems easier and you can redo this with a newer release. Or get a bigger USB ;-)

Comment: GRUB boot is something new to me! Just googled it and I'm already deterred by the difficulty of finding a straightforward tutorial for installing it on Windows... looks like I'll just have to get a bigger USB

Comment: Yeah the 8GB usb is less than $10 at your local store I'm sure. Cheaper USBs are slower but hopefully you'll only be installing once!

Comment: @IceTea but your alternative with isomaster is worse ;-) Ok another method: take the server version and post-install the desktop Heck take the 40mb MINI iso and post install the desktop  :D

Comment: On the server version, you can use the `tasksel` command to install a desktop after installation.

Comment: Alright thanks guys! Will definitely keep in mind the post-install desktop option. For now, I'll just get another USB to save myself a few more hours of googling around.